# Поиск выигрышных ситуаций для неограниченных крестиков-ноликов

Tags: массивы, java, алгоритм, разработка-игр, поиск

Каким способом можно наиболее эффективно найти на игровом поле координаты всех ячеек, заполнение которых приведёт к выигрышу?

Соответственно возможны следующие варианты: **`XXX_`**, **`XX_X`**, **`X_XX`**, **`_XXX`** по горизонтали, аналогичные по вертикали и по обеим диагоналям. (**`X`** — занятая ячейка, **`_`** — пустая)

Сначала я искал простым проходом всего массива: ставил на пустую клетку сначала X, затем O и каждый раз проверял некий checkWin(), есть ли победитель.

Однако, так как поле условно «неограниченно», этот вариант работает слишком медленно, нужно что-то более эффективное.

Как это можно сделать? Неужели единственный вариант — городить кучу if'ов и проверять каждую из шестнадцати возможных ситуаций?

(язык Java)

Comment: If'ы быстрее цикла от 1 до 16 работать не будут... И не спасут от неограниченности поля - теоретически, если поставить крестик/нолик вдалеке от основных построений, в дальнейшем игра может дойти и дотуда, и он сыграет свою роль. Т.е. количество возможных ходов не ограничено.




Если же Ваш вопрос - как быстро проверить, появилась ли линия из 4-х крестиков/ноликов после установки ещё одного - проверяйте только окрестность изменённой клетки, тут действительно может получиться наглядней и быстрее 4-кой похожих циклов (первый - влево-вправо, второй - по диагонали слева сверху вниз, ...)

Comment: А вообще, вроде, есть достаточно простая выигрышная стратегия для первого игрока, поищите

Comment: Нет, вопрос не в этом. Требуется именно что найти все клетки, заполнение которых приведёт к победе одно из игроков. (проверить на шаг вперёд их, как бы).

Comment: Храните координаты уже заполненных клеток в списке и проверяйте окрестность каждой из таких клеток.

Comment: даже при бесконечном поле проверять все клетки не нужно. Если в заданной точке на поле нет соседей, то поставив в нее крестик, выиграть нельзя (данным ходом).

Comment: У вас ведь 4х4, да? Вот выигрышная стратегия:

1. Ход в произвольную клетку.
2. Ход в соседнюю клетку в той же строке (если нолик не в той же строке) или столбце.
3. Достраиваем тройку с одной или другой стороны.
4. Если соперник не прикрыл тройку с обеих сторон двумя предыдущими ходами, достраиваем четвёрку. Если прикрыл с обеих сторон, у него кроме строки/столбца с тройкой только один нолик. Ставим крестик буквой Т, у нас получаются три пары, из которых как минимум две открытые.
5. Своим ходом соперник прикрывает не более одной пары. Достраиваем вторую до открытой с обеих сторон тройки.

Comment: @VladD, так тут построенная 4-ка это уже выигрыш?

Невнимательно я прочел вопрос. Мы всегда играли 5-ку на листочке от тетрадки...

По моему, там очевидной стратегии для выигрыша нет.

Comment: @avp: ТС об этом не говорит (я сначала вообще подумал, что там тройки), но в вопросе он ищет варианты именно для четвёрки, и называет их выигрышными.

Comment: @avp, да, сейчас я так и поступаю: проверяю только смежные к занятым ячейкам. Однако, как показывает практика, это тоже не самый оптимальный вариант, т.к. много «времени» уходит на сохранение смежных к занятым клеток, а после отмены хода (это часть алгоритма ИИ) нужно снова «отменять» те клетки, которые были помечены как смежные...

Comment: @fastZtx, много времени -- это сколько (в секундах)?

Если у Вас "глубокий" перебор всех возможных ходов, то оптимизация структуры данных все равно положение не спасет. 

В любом случае дерево перебора, начиная с некоторой глубины, нужно будет усекать, отбрасывая неперспективные ветки. А как оценить, отбрасывать ветку или нет -- это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @avp, то, что описано в вопросе — это и есть часть функции оценки текущего состояния.
Перебор ведётся на самом деле довольно глубокий. Используется бета-отсечение, само собой.
Однако на последнем «уровне глубины» нужно оценивать текущее состояние на игровом поле, что и делается поиском того, что описано в вопросе

Comment: @fastZtx, Вы так и не сказали, профилировать программу и делать реальные замеры пробовали?

Ну и учтите, Java не лучший вариант, если Вы хотите каких-то "микро" (на уровне представления данных в памяти и основанного на этом ускорения поиска интересных областей) оптимизаций.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы шел не от всей простыни с ходами и перебора всех возможных комбинаций, а от текущих ходов.

1. Поставили крестик.
2. Проверяем выигрыши в восьми направлениях, т.е. добавил ли он выигрышных комбинаций (на след ход).
3. Запоминаем список клеток, ход крестиком на которые будет выигрышным. Плюс для каждой такой клетки координаты собственно выигрышной комбинации (n клеток).
4. Поставили нолик.
5. Проходим по всем выигрышным ходам крестиком, и вычеркиваем перекрытые ходы.

аналогично для ноликов.

Таким образом после каждого очередного хода у нас будет список клеток для обоих игроков, сходив на которые, они могут выиграть.